# How to group Node/Express routes by type in separate files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

My `/router/index.js` file is starting to get awfully crowded and I was hoping to separate my routes by group (user routes, post routes, gear routes) into their own files in `/router/routes/`. Here's what I currently have working:

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');

// database connection
require('./models/posts');
require('./models/Comments');
require('./models/Users');
require('./models/Gear');
//mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/news');

var router = require('./router');
var app = express();

app.use('/', router);

// login setup
require('./config/passport');
app.use(passport.initialize());

// logger
// create a write stream (in append mode)
var accessLogStream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/access.log', {flags: 'a'})
// setup the logger
app.use(logger('combined', {stream: accessLogStream}))
app.use(logger('dev'));

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// TODO: add favicon
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// don't print stacktraces for user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

**/router/index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Post = mongoose.model('Post');
var Comment = mongoose.model('Comment');
var Gear = mongoose.model('Gear');
var passport = require('passport');
var jwt = require('express-jwt');


var User = mongoose.model('User');
var auth = jwt({secret: 'SECRET', userProperty: 'payload'});

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

/*
 * Posts routes
 */

/* GET all posts */
router.get('/posts', function(req, res, next) {
  Post.find(function(err, posts) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(posts);
  })
});

/* POST add new post */
router.post('/posts', auth, function(req, res, next) {
  var post = new Post(req.body);
  post.author = req.payload.username;

  post.save(function(err, post) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(post);
  })
});

/* preload post */
router.param('post', function(req, res, next, id) {
  var query = Post.findById(id);

  query.exec(function(err, post) {
    if(err) return next(err);
    if (!post) return next(new Error('can\'t find post'));

    req.post = post;
    return next();
  })
});

/* GET single post */
router.get('/posts/:post', function(req, res, next) {
  req.post.populate('comments', function(err, post) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }

    res.json(post);
  });
});

/* PUT upvote a post */
router.put('/posts/:post/upvote', auth, function(req, res, next) {
  req.post.upvote(function(err, post) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(post);
  })
});

/* PUT downvote a post */
router.put('/posts/:post/downvote', auth, function(req, res, next) {
  req.post.downvote(function(err, post) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(post);
  })
});

/*
 * Comment routes
 */

/* POST comment on single post */
router.post('/posts/:post/comments', auth, function(req, res, next) {
  var comment = new Comment(req.body);
  comment.post = req.post;
  comment.author = req.payload.username;

  comment.save(function(err, comment){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    req.post.comments.push(comment);
    req.post.save(function(err, post) {
      if(err){ return next(err); }

      res.json(comment);
    });
  });
});

/* preload comment */
router.param('comment', function(req, res, next, id) {
  var query = Comment.findById(id);

  query.exec(function(err, comment) {
    if(err) return next(err);
    if (!comment) return next(new Error('can\'t find comment'));

    req.comment = comment;
    return next();
  })
});

/* GET single comment */
router.get('/posts/:post/comments/:comment', function(req, res) {
  res.json(req.comment);
});

/* PUT upvote comment on a post */
router.put('/posts/:post/comments/:comment/upvote', auth, function(req, res, next) {
  req.comment.upvote(function(err, comment) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(comment);
  })
});

/* PUT downvote a comment on a post */
router.put('/posts/:post/comments/:comment/downvote', auth, function(req, res, next) {
  req.comment.downvote(function(err, comment) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(comment);
  })
});

/*
 * User routes
 */

/* POST Create User */
router.post('/register', function(req, res, next) {
  if(!req.body.username || !req.body.password) {
    return res.status(400).json({message: "Please fill out all fields"});
  }

  var user = new User();
  user.username = req.body.username;
  user.setPassword(req.body.password);

  user.save(function(err) {
    if (err) return next(err);

    return res.json({token: user.generateJWT()})
  });
});

/* POST login page */
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next){
  if(!req.body.username || !req.body.password){
    return res.status(400).json({message: 'Please fill out all fields'});
  }

  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    if(user){
      return res.json({token: user.generateJWT()});
    } else {
      return res.status(401).json(info);
    }
  })(req, res, next);
});

/*
 *  Gear routes
 */

 /* GET all gear */
 router.get('/gear', function(req, res, next) {
   Gear.find(function(err, gear) {
     if (err) return next(err);
     res.json(gear);
   })
 });

 /* preload gear item */
 router.param('item', function(req, res, next, id) {
   var query = Gear.findById(id);

   query.exec(function(err, item) {
     if(err) return next(err);
     if (!item) return next(new Error('can\'t find item'));

     req.item = item;
     return next();
   })
 });

 /* GET single gear item */
 router.get('/gear/:item', function(req, res, next) {
   req.item.populate('item', function(err, item) {
     if (err) { return next(err); }

     res.json(item);
   });
 });

 /* POST add new gear */
 router.post('/gear', auth, function(req, res, next) {
   var gear = new Gear(req.body);
   gear.owner = req.payload.username;

   gear.save(function(err, gear) {
     if (err) return next(err);
     res.json(gear);
   })
 });

 /* DELETE single gear item */
router.delete('/gear/:item/delete', auth, function(req, res, next) {
  var query = Gear.findById(req.item, function(err, item) {
    if (err) { return next(err) };
    item.remove();
  }).exec();

  return res.json();
});

module.exports = router;
```

I have a tried a few different ways of putting all the `posts` routes in `/router/routes/post-routes.js`, like so:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var jwt = require('express-jwt');
var auth = jwt({secret: 'SECRET', userProperty: 'payload'});

/*
 * Posts routes
 */

/* GET all posts */
router.get('/posts', function(req, res, next) {
  Post.find(function(err, posts) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(posts);
  })
});

/* POST add new post */
router.post('/posts', auth, function(req, res, next) {
  var post = new Post(req.body);
  post.author = req.payload.username;

  post.save(function(err, post) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(post);
  })
});

/* preload post */
router.param('post', function(req, res, next, id) {
  var query = Post.findById(id);

  query.exec(function(err, post) {
    if(err) return next(err);
    if (!post) return next(new Error('can\'t find post'));

    req.post = post;
    return next();
  })
});

/* GET single post */
router.get('/posts/:post', function(req, res, next) {
  req.post.populate('comments', function(err, post) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }

    res.json(post);
  });
});

/* PUT upvote a post */
router.put('/posts/:post/upvote', auth, function(req, res, next) {
  req.post.upvote(function(err, post) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(post);
  })
});

/* PUT downvote a post */
router.put('/posts/:post/downvote', auth, function(req, res, next) {
  req.post.downvote(function(err, post) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(post);
  })
});

module.exports = router;
```

with the following in `/router/index.js`:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    var routeFiles = fs.readdirSync(__dirname)

    routeFiles.forEach(function(file) {
        if (file === "index.js" || file.substr(file.lastIndexOf('.') + 1) !== 'js')
            return;
        var name = file.substr(0, file.indexOf('.'));
        require('./' + name)(app);
    });
}
```

At this point, I just don't know what I am missing. My goal file structure would be this:

```
app.js
/router
   - index.js
   /routes
      - post-routes.js
      - user-routes.js
      - comment-routes.js
```

Answer (score 1):

If that is your /router/index.js, then you would need

```
var path = require('path')

// ...

var routeFiles = fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, 'routes'))
```

instead of

```
var routeFiles = fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
```

Otherwise you will be reading the wrong directory listing (/router instead of /router/routes).

You will also need to change the `require()` of your routes appropriately so that the path is correct (`'./routes/' + name`).

Lastly, your ./router/routes/ files are merely exporting routers and not exporting functions that take an `app`, which is not what your ./router/index.js is expecting. So you can do one of two things:

- Change the exports of each ./router/routes/ file to export a function that adds its router to `app`:

  ```
  module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(router);
  };
  ```
- Change the ./router/index.js file to not call the modules' exports as functions but instead mount the exports on `app`:

  ```
  app.use(require('./routes/' + name));
  ```

Comment: Ok!  Moving in the right direction.  I changed that and also changed `require('./' + name)(app);` to be `require('./routes/' + name)(app);`.

I am now getting

 ```Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at /Users/grahamlutz/Documents/Personal/practice/my-virtual-pack/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:618:14
    ...
```

Comment: Do I need to do something other than this in app.js?

`var router = require('./router');
app.use('/', router);`